# Identify one particular field with RegEx

Tags: c, regex, loadrunner

Apologies for the basic question but I'm new to regular expressions and am really struggling to find a solution to the problem I am facing.

I am trying to pull out a particular field from a json response dynamically, which can change each time I call it.

The response is:

```
[{"colorPartNumber":"10045112022164298","skuPartNumber":"0400218072057","productColor":{"identifier":"Dark blue","label":"Dark blue","hex":"#0000A0"},"productSize":{"identifier":"0","label":"0","name":"Designer","scaleLabel":"apparel-wmn","schema":{"name":"UK","labels":["8"]}},"soldOut":true,"onlyOneLeft":false,"limitedAvailability":false,"preorder":false,"comingSoon":false,"visible":true,"displayable":true,"buyable":false,"availableInPhysicalStore":false,"expectedShippingDate":null},{"colorPartNumber":"10045112022164298","skuPartNumber":"0400094632819","productColor":{"identifier":"Dark blue","label":"Dark blue","hex":"#0000A0"},"productSize":{"identifier":"1","label":"1","name":"Designer","scaleLabel":"apparel-wmn","schema":{"name":"UK","labels":["10"]}},"soldOut":true,"onlyOneLeft":false,"limitedAvailability":false,"preorder":false,"comingSoon":false,"visible":true,"displayable":true,"buyable":false,"availableInPhysicalStore":false,"expectedShippingDate":null},{"colorPartNumber":"10045112022164298","skuPartNumber":"0400218072040","productColor":{"identifier":"Dark blue","label":"Dark blue","hex":"#0000A0"},"productSize":{"identifier":"2","label":"2","name":"Designer","scaleLabel":"apparel-wmn","schema":{"name":"UK","labels":["12"]}},"soldOut":true,"onlyOneLeft":false,"limitedAvailability":false,"preorder":false,"comingSoon":false,"visible":true,"displayable":true,"buyable":false,"availableInPhysicalStore":false,"expectedShippingDate":null},{"colorPartNumber":"10045112022164298","skuPartNumber":"0400468014814","productColor":{"identifier":"Dark blue","label":"Dark blue","hex":"#0000A0"},"productSize":{"identifier":"3","label":"3","name":"Designer","scaleLabel":"apparel-wmn","schema":{"name":"UK","labels":["14"]}},"soldOut":false,"onlyOneLeft":true,"limitedAvailability":false,"preorder":false,"comingSoon":false,"visible":true,"displayable":true,"buyable":true,"availableInPhysicalStore":false,"expectedShippingDate":null}]
```

I am trying to pull out the skuPartNumber, but only when the "buyable" value is set to true.

Every thing I try I cannot seem to get just this one value :(

So in the example above the only value I want to pull out is `0400468014814`.

This json is dynamic so there could be 100 values coming back, but the principle is the same.

One example of a failed attempt is `skuPartNumber(.*?)"buyable":true`, which only gives me the very first value (`0400218072057`), which is wrong.

Once again sorry for the basic question.

Comment: Why use regex for this task and not just parse the JSON with a library? Seems like overengineering.

Comment: Good question. I am using a tool called LoadRunner to performance test an application. As part of this I need to grab values dynamically from JSON responses and push them into subsequent requests. LoadRunner doesn't have much support for JSON but it does support RegEx, so this seemed like a good choice.

Comment: [LoadRunner seems to support JSON parsing.](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/Get-a-new-way-to-manipulate-JSON-with-load-testing-in-LoadRunner/ba-p/234409#.WUDpx2j1CUk)

Comment: You can use web_reg_save_param_json instead of web_reg_save_param_regex and then use the simple query language to extract what you need. See the documentation for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
\"skuPartNumber\":\"(\d+)\"(?:[^}]*?\}){3}[^}]*?\"buyable\":true
```

Your answer is in the first match group.

Comment: @Shaqattack Make sure to accept an answer that worked.